# react app loaded as widget to a container at customer website

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I will be building an app that is suppose to be serving as a widget and i wanted to use react to do so, but i just started with react, i created app using "Create React App", i made some components and i have working prototype in development environment but ...

The guys asked that they will give me an `id` of a container where widget should be placed and they are asking for `css` and `js` links and they expect widget to be build in there.

I started inspecting my environment and i kind of dont know where to start, in sources i see that there is gazilion packages connected and some 40k lines bundle.js file.

Is it possible that the customer on his website just puts:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="__LINK_TO_SERVER__app.css">
<div id="app-widget"><!-- APP WILL BE HERE --></div>
<script src="__LINK_TO_SERVER__/app.js"></script>
```

and this app will be working?

If so, what are the steps to make it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's completely possible.
2. You may include `<link rel="stylesheet">` insertion into your js bundle
3. Don't forget about `async` option: `<script async src="__LINK_TO_SERVER__/app.js"></script>`